# accessing Meteor.users.emails[0].address in Meteor.publish

Tags: meteor

I want to publish a collection to the owner which is accessed by this.userId (that part is working) and to those that the owner has invited. The only way I can do this is through the invited.email in my collection because the user being invited may not be a registered user yet.

```
Meteor.publish("meals", function () {
  var current_user = Meteor.user();
    return MealModel.find(
  {$or: [{"invited.email": current_user.emails[0].address}, {owner: this.userId}]});
});
```

I don't want to publish the entire collection and query on the client side because I  am afraid the collection could potentially get too big.

Any suggestions?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't use [Meteor.user()](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_user) inside of a publish function. Instead, you need to do a `findOne` with the `userId`. Give this a try:

```js
Meteor.publish('meals', function() {
  if (!this.userId)
    return this.ready();

  var user = Meteor.users.findOne(this.userId);
  var email = user.emails[0].address;
  return MealModel.find({$or: [{'invited.email': email}, {owner: this.userId}]});
});
```

Comment: Pardon, but shouldn't the return part be {owner: user} instead of {owner: this.userId} ? (My Metoer experience is currently quite limited so take it with a grain of salt)

Comment: @EvilBeer I think you may be correct since user is already called there is no point in calling it again, right?

Comment: @David Weldon That was it thanks. I'd vote you up but my reputation is lacking.

Comment: @EvilBeer `user` is an object, `this.userId` or `user._id` (these are the same) are strings. My assumption is that the `MealModel` documents are inserted with `owner` as an id (normal) rather than an object (unusual).

Comment: @DavidWeldon ah, that makes sense. Apologies